# How can I override css style with className?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following style for my `<li>` tag inside a .css file:

```
li {
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: #32383d;
 transition: 0.4s;
 border-bottom: 1.5px solid #464e53;
 color: #6b6d6d;
 font-family: "Poppins", Arial, sans-serif;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Now the problem is that I want to add an `active` class to the current selected `<li>` using `className` attribute :

```
filteredItem[0].items.forEach((menuItem, index) => {
    menuItems.push(<li key={index} className={`${index === currentPage ? 'active' : ''}`}><span
        className={menuItem.css}/>{menuItem.value}</li>)
});
```

And the `active` class style : (inside the same .css file)

```
.active {
 background-color: #2f89fc;
}
```

But this doesn't override the original background-color. Any help ?

*NOTE*: The `currentPage` variable is working as expected. (tested it with `background-color` removed from `li`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give it a higher specifity:

```
li.active {
 background-color: #2f89fc;
}
```

Comment: I want this `active` class to be usable for more elements.

Comment: well, if it *does* work with the `li`, you could still use a selector like `li.active, p.active, div.active { ... }` (Depending on the type of elements to which you wanrt to add your class)

Comment: Yes, it works. But it works with "!important" at the end too. Which approach is better?

Comment: I think the combined selectors are better, without `!important` . `!important` should only ever be the last solution if nothing else works. You might want to overwrite that rule in some other situation later on, and then `!important` is not nice to handle...

Comment: Got it. Thank you.